# How do I solve this non-linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, newton-raphson

I have a formula describing a non-linear system which is as follows:

$-y(x)'' + A|y(x)|^2y(x) = k^2 y(x)$

where A is a constant that I can choose to be a positive or negative integer. I also have Dirichlet and Nuemann boundary conditions that I can vary.

I know that in the case of A=0, we have the equation
$y'' = k^2 y$ which can easily be solved with the ansatz

$Acos(kx) + Bsin(kx)$

which I can then apply my boundary conditions to. But I am unsure of how to reach a solution when A is a positive or negative integer. I know that I most likely need to convert the equation to a recursion relation so I can make use of Newtons Method but I have no idea how to do so correctly, Could anyone could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you intend the absolute value of $y$ rather than of $y^2$? And if $A$ can be either positive or negative, why do you need absolute value?

Comment: I've edited the question, I intended it to be the absolute value of y all squared, rather than what it was before.

Comment: @JamesC Is $y$ a complex-valued function? If it's real valued then $|y|^2 = y^2$ and this is the [Duffing equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation).

Comment: In that case, the absolute value is completely unneccessary and your equation is $-y(x)'' + Ay(x)^3 = k^2 y(x)$

Comment: Thankyou for your help thus far, the link @eyeballfrog shared helps for calculating real valued solutions! I'm using y to refer to the wavefunction however I think I only need to calculate real valued solutions so that should be sufficient. I'll close the question tomorrow if I manage to produce some solutions.